# How to convert matrix to cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have matrix A = 50x2
How to convert the data into cell array.
Should be I have 10 cell which each cell contain data [5x2].

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

That is what [`mat2cell`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) does:

```
A = rand(50,2); % example matrix
N = 10; % number of cells in which to split the first dimension
result = mat2cell(A, repmat(size(A,1)/N, 1, N), size(A,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
N_ROWS = 5; N_COLS = 2;
A = rand(50,2);
B = num2cell(reshape(A,N_ROWS,N_COLS,[]),[1,2]); % B is 1x1x10 cell array
```

What this does is turn your input array into 5x2 "slices" stacked along the 3rd dimension.

You can add a `squeeze(B)`, `B = B(:)` or a `reshape(B,[],1)` at the end if you need the output as a column vector.